# Django using try: and except:

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, exception

I was wondering if its possible to write a handling exceptions like with 2 or more except with different task to do.

I'm using  `Django==1.6.1` and `Python 2.7`

```
try:
    foo_instance = foo.objects.get(field_name='unknown')

except foo.DoesNotExist:
    new_rec = foo.objects.create(field_name='unknown')
    new_rec.save()

    foo_instance = foo.objects.get(field_name='unknown')

except foo.MultipleObjectsReturned:
    foo_list = foo.objects.filter(field_name='unknown')
    for record in foo_list[1:]:
       print 'Deleting foo id: ', record.id
       record.delete()

    foo_instance = foo.objects.get(field_name='unknown')
```

Comment: It's still python, you can do this. Is there a problem with the code you've provided?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095717/python-one-try-multiple-except

Comment: Thanks alecxe. The traceback pointing me to the second except line.

Comment: But finally found the cause of my error.  THe original code for `foo_list` is `em_list = EquipModel.objects.filter(make=ppp_detail[i]))`. It has an extra right parenthesis. ><

Comment: sorry sfletche..fail to search that link. Thanks for the link

Comment: Was wondering why my `DoesNotExist` exception was not taking...looks like it needs to be `except {{Model}}.DoesNotExist:`, where `{{Model}}` is the name of whatever model we're working with. Thanks for adding this example, helped get me out of a bind!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use multiple `try: except:` but in your current scenario Why don't you use [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) ?

try: expect: contain all errors on 'Exception'. for this syntax is all

```
except Exception as e:
```

> get_or_create(defaults=None, **kwargs)
>
> A convenience method for looking up an object with the given kwargs
> (may be empty if your model has defaults for all fields), creating one
> if necessary.
>
> Returns a tuple of (object, created), where object is the retrieved or
> created object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new
> object was created.

This reduces your above code to -

```
 obj, created = foo.objects.get_or_create(field_name='unknown')
 if created:
     obj.save()
```

I think `get_or_create` raises [`IntegrityError`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.db.IntegrityError) or [`MultipleObjectsReturned`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.MultipleObjectsReturned), to handle those simply wrap it in a try:

```
try:
    obj, created = foo.objects.get_or_create(field_name='unknown')
    if created:
        obj.save()
except IntegrityError: 
    #do something
except MultipleObjectsReturned:
    #do something else
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

Comment: explended used of get_or_create, well explain. Thx Srikar Appal