# Python Try/Except with multiple except blocks

Tags: python, exception

```
try:
    raise KeyError()
except KeyError:
    print "Caught KeyError"
    raise Exception()
except Exception:
    print "Caught Exception"
```

As expected, raising `Exception()` on the 5th line isn't caught in the final `except Exception` clause. In order the catch the exception inside of the `except KeyError` block, I have to add another `try...except` like this and duplicate the final `except Exception` logic:

```
try:
    raise KeyError()
except KeyError:
    print "Caught KeyError"
    try:
        raise Exception()
    except Exception:
        print "Caught Exception"
except Exception:
    print "Caught Exception"
```

In Python, is it possible to pass the flow of execution to the final `except Exception` block like I am trying to do? If not, are there strategies for reducing the duplication of logic?

Comment: Yes. Put the code you're using to handle `Exception` in a function. Then call that function in both places.

Comment: `except` clauses only catch errors thrown in the `try`; otherwise, you couldn't re-raise if you wanted to.

Comment: hmmm, can you explain what you are trying to achieve?  the standard approach to re-raising a caught exception that you've decided not to handle after all is `raise`, without anything else.  That may or may not fit your reqs in this case.  Can't tell from your code alone.

Comment: I'll give even stronger suggestion than @JLPeyret: *Do not use exceptions for flow control*. What are you actually trying to achieve? There might be more elegant solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could add another level of `try` nesting:

```
try:
    try:
        raise KeyError()
    except KeyError:
        print "Caught KeyError"
        raise Exception()
except Exception:
    print "Caught Exception"
```