# Catch specific errors in python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, exception, error-handling

I was trying to catch a specific exception:

```
username = 'myuser'
try:
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    print(user)
except Exception as e:
    if type(e)=='django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist':
        print('No such user')

    print (type(e))
```

But instead of going into the if loop, I am getting:

```
<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist'>
```

Why is this happening? How can I catch a specific exception?

Comment: Because `type(e)` does not return a string. The `if` condition should be `if type(e) == django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist` or better, `if isinstance(e, django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist)`. But the correct overall solution would be JPG's answer

Answer (score 4):

`type(e)` does not return a string. Note that

```
(<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist'> != 
 'django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist')
```

The `if` condition should be `if type(e) == django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist` or better, `if isinstance(e, django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist)`

However, the correct solution is to use multiple **`except`** clauses

```
username = 'myuser'
try:
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    print(user)
except User.DoesNotExist:
    # do something
    print('No such user')
except SomeOtherException:
    # do a different thing
except Foo:
    # do bar
```

Note that you can also combine handling of different exception types to the same `except` clause:

```
try:
    # some bad code
except (User.DoesnotExist, SomeOtherException):
    # error handling code
```

**Reference**
1. [Python: One Try Multiple Except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095717/python-one-try-multiple-except)

Comment: For the sake of completeness I'd add an explanation as to *why* OP's code does not work (see my comment)