# How to avoid long chain of try and except statements?

Tags: python, exception

I'm trying to locate search boxes on websites using the Mechanize python package to find forms on web pages. Pretty much every website defines these forms in their own way so I need to search for a bunch of different signatures. Because the Mechanize Browser.select_form function throws an exception whenever it fails to find the specified form, looking for a lot of different forms turns into a long list of try and except statements.

The first thing I tried(or rolled into) is the following structure. It works, but 1: it doesn't look very good, 2: expands badly(if I need even more statements this turns into chaos) and 3: overal this just seems like bad code.

```py
from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()
br.open(url)
try:
    br.select_form(id=lambda x: 'search' in x)
except Exception:
    try:
        br.select_form(class_=lambda x: 'search' in x)
    except Exception:
        try:
            br.select_form(action=lambda x: 'search' in x)
        except Exception:
            try:
                br.select_form(role=lambda x: 'search' in x)
            except Exception:
                print('NOTHING FOUND')
                pass
```

A possibly slightly better solution would to direct the except clauses to functions, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6095782/11309912. This would solve the sideways expansion but still consists of a lot of repeated code.

To me the ideal solution would be to have a list of statements I could iterate over until one type of form was found. A very crude example would be:

```py
forms = ['id=lambda x: 'search' in x', 'class_=lambda x: 'search' in x', .....]
for form in forms:
    try:
        br.select_form(form)
        break
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Is something similar to this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing that's variable there is the name of the keyword argument passed to `select_form`, and you can pass variable keywords like this:

```
for attr in ('id', 'search', 'class_', 'role'):
    try:
        form = br.select_form(**{attr: lambda x: 'search' in x})
        break
    except:
        pass
else:
    print('NOTHING FOUND')
```

Comment: Is it not bad to handle a bare `Exception` instead of the right exception, something like `except ValueError:` (for ex)?

Comment: Absolutely, you *should* catch a specific error there. OP is catching `Exception`, which is just as bad, so I omitted it entirely. I'm not sure what exceptions `select_form` will raise exactly, so can't fill in that part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about with mechanize, but I know it's possible with selenium. More or less exactly like the example you used, actually.  I won't be using lambda in this next example but it'll give the same effect just a bit slower.  Assume driver is the variable pointer name for my browser.

```py
listOfPossibleFields = ["user", "username", "un", "name", "login"]
for word in listOfPossibleFields:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_name(word)
    except Exception:
         pass
```

Comment: Thanks, @Arne!  I'm on mobile and try as I might, I keep missing auto-capitalizations like that.

Comment: happy to help =)

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more generic, you can create a class for each of the search patterns and then to iterate thought a list of those classes instances.

```
class IdSearchPattern(object):
    def search(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

class RoleSearchPattern(object):
    def search(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

search_patterns = [IdSearchPattern(), RoleSearchPattern()]
for sp in search_patterns:
    try:
        result = sp.search()
        break
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Sometimes this is a good solution and sometimes it is a little bit of overdesign.

Note: I wrote this answer from my phone, code is not tested.