# Python try/except - best practices / optimisation

Tags: python, performance, optimization, try-except

I'm looking for some information about best practices for try/except block in Python.
I've meet few different approaches but I cannot find any proves/docs that one of them is the best to use.

**Which one has the best performance and why?**

1. All i one

```py
def get_information():
    try:
        foo = some_func(1)  # may raise KeyError
        bar = some_func(2)  # may raise ValueError
        return foo + baar
    except (KeyError, ValueError):
        logger.info('Lala')
        raise
```

2. try/except without else

```py
def get_information():
    try:
        foo = some_func(1)  # may raise KeyError
        bar = some_func(2)  # may raise ValueError
    except (KeyError, ValueError):
        logger.info('Lala')
        raise
    return foo + bar
```

3. try/except with else

```py
def get_information():
    try:
        foo = some_func(1)  # may raise KeyError
        bar = some_func(2)  # may raise ValueError
    except (KeyError, ValueError):
        logger.info('Lala')
        raise
    else:
        return foo + bar
```

4. Separate all

```py
def get_information():
    try:
        foo = some_func(1)  # may raise KeyError
    except KeyError:
        logger.info('KeyError')
        raise

    try:
        bar = some_func(2)  # may raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        logger.info('ValueError')
        raise

    return foo + bar
```

Thank you

Comment: My vote is #1, but that's just my opinion. In reality, use whatever works for you/your team.

Comment: I see 1 and 2 most often. I rarely see the `try/else` syntax used. I only see 4 in the case of wanting to do unique things based on each error - even then `dictionary dispatch` often works well. What is most important is to just pick a convention and stick to it.

Comment: For #1, you may want to just use [multiple excepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095717/python-one-try-multiple-except) instead

Comment: All 4 of these do entirely different things. They are not about best, they are about what needs to be done *for a specific problem*.