# How to handle multiple exceptions in Python 3?

Tags: python, exception, tkinter

I am creating a Calculator application using Tkinter. I require multiple types of exception statements to intimate the user by different types of outputs for different exceptions caused by him.

**For example:**

> If the user divides a number by zero, then division by zero error arises. In this case I must create an exception statement that handles only division by zero error.

> At the same time, if the user enters an invalid operation like '100++2' instead of '100+2' then an invalid syntax error arises. In this case I must specify a different exception statement in the same **try** to handle this condition differently.

So, how to do this?

Comment: Show us some code, please. Sounds like you're looking for `try: except ...:` with different `...`s; see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: One Try Multiple Except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095717/python-one-try-multiple-except)

Comment: Try `tkinter.messagebox.showerror` after catching it with `try` and `except`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be worth checking out the [Errors and Exceptions docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

In short, you can specify behaviour for different Exception types using the `except ExceptionType:` syntax where `ExceptionType` is an `Exception` derived from the Python `Exception` class - a list of built-in Python exceptions can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html).

It is important to note that when an `Exception` is raised in a `try` block, Python will execute the code within the first `Except` block that matches the `Exception` raised in a top-down manner. For this reason, `except Exception:` is usually found at the bottom in a given `try`/`except` chain as to provide default behaviour for unspecified exceptions that may be raised, it is not first as any `Exception` raised will trigger this behaviour and thus would make other `Except` statements within the chain moot.

**Example**

The below example illustrates the above points.

Here `eval()` has been used for demonstrative purposes only, please be aware of the inherent dangers of using `eval()` before you consider using it in your own code.

```py
def demo(e):
    try:
        eval(e)
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print("ZeroDivisionError caught")
        print(e)
    except IndexError as e:
        print("IndexError caught")
        print(e)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Other Exception caught")
        print(e)
    
examples = ["10/0", "[0,1,2][5]", "int('foo')"]

for e in examples:
    demo(e)
    print()
```

**Output**

```
ZeroDivisionError caught
division by zero

IndexError caught
list index out of range

Other Exception caught
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'foo'
```