# Python make different actions for specific type of exception (depending on what it catches

Tags: python, exception

While executing a try except process, I get different types of exceptions, there is one exactly that I want the process to act different than with the others.

This is my process, as simple as that:

```
try:
    variable = do_something()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    continue
```

It catches different types of exceptions during the process, but the exact exception I want to address differently is:

```
Message: invalid session id
Stacktrace:
#0 0x56107b4a8e89 <unknown>
```

I am thinking on addressing the following way:

```
if 'invalid session id' in str(e):
            print('passing')
            pass
```

But I would like to know if there is a more elegant of pythonic way to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: One Try Multiple Except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095717/python-one-try-multiple-except)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can catch different types of exceptions by using the classes

```
import sys

try:
    # Do something
except EOFError as e:
    print(e)
except AnotherError as f:
    print(f)
excepe Exception as g:
    #Reach here if no specific exception was caught
    print(g)
```