# How can I put an action that applied on every exception in python?

Tags: python, exception, code-duplication

I wrote something similar to the following code, and there is duplicated code (process_error) on every exception. But there are duplications.

```
try:
    do_something()
    ...
except KeyError:
    process_error()
    ...
except ValueError:
    process_error()
    ...
except:
    process_error()
    ...
```

So I changed the code like this.

```
try:
    try:
        do_something()
        ...

    except:
        process_error()
        raise
except KeyError:
    ...
except ValueError:
    ...
except:
    ...
```

I feel like this is very ugly. Is there any better structure than this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One try block with multiple excepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095717/one-try-block-with-multiple-excepts)

Comment: First of all, if you have `except: process_error()` all other exception types are irrelevant since plain `except` will catch all of them. On the other hand, this is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @NotAName No, the OP's approach would work too since the `raise` statement reraises the original exception so that the outer `try` block would still catch it and let type-specific exception handlers handle the exception.

Comment: @jolim I believe what makes your approach "ugly" is the fact that the main logics are placed in a nested `try` block two levels deep. The answer in the linked question, although still a solution that relies on nesting, is arguably cleaner by placing the main logics on the first level of a `try` block.